# OPENSSL ERROR C++ 17 error:80000005:system library::Input/output error when passing path to client cert file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I am trying to create a TLS GUI Client using c++/WinRT.
The TLS Client I am using is https://github.com/embeddedmz/socket-cpp

For some reason when I try to connect to the socket server the connection fails when using the BlankApp(C++/WinRT Template) and no errors thrown.

When I test it with the blank console application, it works. Everything is the same across the board except the one being a console application and the other being a BlankApp(C++/WinRT Template) application.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

C++ Version: IS0 C++ 17 Standard

**Update 12/16/2022 **

I finally got OPENSSL to print errors to Visual Studio Debugger.
I have the following error.

Code that fails

```
int e = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(m_SSLConnectSocket.m_pCTXSSL, m_strSSLCertFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
```

That function should return a `1` but returns `-2147483643` and this is the error in I get from [ERR_error_string](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/ERR_error_string.html) method:
`error:80000005:system library::Input/output error`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: How ever I know that SSL_New on this line https://github.com/embeddedmz/socket-cpp/blob/master/Socket/TCPSSLClient.cpp#L105 is returning a null pointer wen it should return an SSL connection state, But it does not make sense that the exact same code works in one place versus the other.